# Json decode from URL page

Tags: php, html, json, url, decode

I need decode this json code from URL page.
In url is the json code in format:

```
{"current":{"artists_id":"55","albums_id":null,"albums_tracks_id":null},"html_current":"<li><p>Pr\u00e1v\u011b hraje <a href=\"http:\/\/www.abradio.cz\/interpret\/55\/no-doubt\/\" title=\"Zobrazit str\u00e1nku interpreta No Doubt\">No Doubt<\/a><\/p><ul><li class=\"first\"><a href=\"http:\/\/www.abradio.cz\/interpret\/55\/no-doubt\/diskografie\/\" title=\"\">Diskografie<\/a><\/li><li><a href=\"http:\/\/www.abradio.cz\/interpret\/55\/no-doubt\/fotky\/\" title=\"\">Fotky<\/a><\/li><li><a href=\"http:\/\/www.abradio.cz\/interpret\/55\/no-doubt\/videa\/\" title=\"\">Videa<\/a><\/li><li><a href=\"http:\/\/www.abradio.cz\/interpret\/55\/no-doubt\/diskuze\/\" title=\"\">Diskuze<\/a><\/li><\/ul><\/li>","html":"<li class=\"previous\"><a href=\"http:\/\/www.abradio.cz\/interpret\/55\/no-doubt\/\" title=\"Zobrazit str\u00e1nku interpreta NO DOUBT\"><img src=\"http:\/\/static.abradio.cz\/data\/p\/0\/2\/7\/14720\/medium.jpg\" alt=\"\" \/><\/a><span class=\"artistname\"><a href=\"http:\/\/www.abradio.cz\/interpret\/55\/no-doubt\/\" title=\"Zobrazit str\u00e1nku interpreta NO DOUBT\">NO DOUBT<\/a><\/span><br \/><span class=\"trackname\">It's My Life<\/span><\/li><li class=\"current\"><span class=\"artistname\"><a href=\"http:\/\/www.abradio.cz\/interpret\/55\/no-doubt\/\" title=\"Zobrazit str\u00e1nku interpreta NO DOUBT\">NO DOUBT<\/a><\/span><br \/><span class=\"trackname\">It's My Life<\/span><a href=\"http:\/\/www.abradio.cz\/interpret\/55\/no-doubt\/\" title=\"Zobrazit str\u00e1nku interpreta NO DOUBT\"><img src=\"http:\/\/static.abradio.cz\/data\/p\/0\/2\/7\/14720\/medium.jpg\" alt=\"\" \/><\/a>&nbsp;<\/li><li class=\"next\"><a href=\"http:\/\/www.abradio.cz\/interpret\/309\/bryan-adams\/\" title=\"Zobrazit str\u00e1nku interpreta BRYAN ADAMS\"><img src=\"\/data\/a\/5425\/cover\/thumb\/c8457f3bea.jpg\" alt=\"\" \/><\/a><span class=\"artistname\"><a href=\"http:\/\/www.abradio.cz\/interpret\/309\/bryan-adams\/\" title=\"Zobrazit str\u00e1nku interpreta BRYAN ADAMS\">BRYAN ADAMS<\/a><\/span><br \/><span class=\"trackname\"><a href=\"http:\/\/www.abradio.cz\/album\/5425\/bare-bones\/44518\/\" title=\"Zobrazit skladbu Please Forgive Me\">Please Forgive Me<\/a><\/span><\/li>","lastchange":1410643066}
```

I write this code, but is not functional. For another json url address functional but here no.

```
<span id="playing"></span>    
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <script>

        //When DOM loaded we attach click event to button
        $(document).ready(function() {


                //start ajax request
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://static.abradio.cz/data/ct/67-popup.json",
                    //force to handle it as text
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(data) {

                        //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function 
                        //and pass downloaded data
                        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                        //now json variable contains data in json format
                        //let's display a few items
                        $('#playing').html('Song: ' + json.html_current + '<br /><br />Author: ' + json.current); 
                    }
                });

            });     
    </script>
```

THX.

Comment: Looks like the data is already JSON formatted, in that case you should be able to use it directly instead of forcing `text` type and then parsing to JSON.

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Run the script. What does the JavaScript console say? Can you see your Ajax request in the Net tab? Is it formatted correctly? Does it get a response? Is the response correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call current before the secondary key.

```
json.current.artist_id
```

And I don't think you need to parse the JSON. Check your escaping as well, I got an error when i plugged it into jsfiddle.net.